# ggarrange gives extra plot on R magic cell in a Python Jupyter notebook

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook, rpy2, ggpubr

I am using `rpy2` to embed `ggplot` plots in my Python Jupyter notebook. I am also using the function `ggarrange()` from `ggpubr` to concatenate multiple plots.

If I add the argument `common.legend` in `ggarrange()`, this R magic cell will display two images (one empty image and one output figure). The cell only displays one figure if `common.legend` is not included.

Here is a [demo](https://gist.github.com/xiaohk/501cfde0e0eb432dcb2cbddcbebf7a57) of this error.

I am not sure if it caused by `rpy2` or `ggarrange()`. Any suggestions are appreciated.